# Try to add variable in attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for checking my checkbox with url parameters.

```
var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf('?');
var types = document.location.href.substr(i+1).replace(/editeur=/g,'').split('&');
$('input[name="editeur"]').prop('checked',function(){
     return $.inArray(this.value,types) !== -1;
});
```

And this the HTML

```html
<div class="hEditeur">
  <input id="edit" name="editeur" type="checkbox" value="edit">
  <label for="edit">
    Editeur 1
    <svg height="18" viewBox="0 0 31 31" width="18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M15.5.5v30m15-15H.5" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="3px"></path>
    </svg>
  </label>
</div>
<section id="domaine">
  <div>
    <input id="domaine1" name="domaine" type="checkbox" value="domaine1" data-editeur="edit">
    <label for="domaine1">Domaine 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="domaine2" name="domaine" type="checkbox" value="domaine2" data-editeur="edit">
    <label for="domaine2">Domaine 2</label>
  </div>
</section>
```

What I want to do now is to add a class='open' to #domaine with the help of the data-editeur and the variable I get with the code in the begining.
I try something like that

```html
$('#domaine input').parent().parent().attr(''+types).addClass('open');
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: How do you know your code doesn't work? There's nothing indicating that in the post.

Comment: To set `attr()`, which I presume is your goal as you can't call `addClass()` on a string, you need to provide two arguments to the function, the key and the value. Also, if you want to add the class to `#domaine` directly, why select the child `input` and use chained `parent()` calls? Select it directly.

Comment: Are you using `.attr(''+types)` to mean "where it matches these types"?  You're probably looking for `.filter()` https://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Can you provide some more examples?  It's unclear what you're *trying* to do.  eg state: when it's X then do Y, when it's not X then do Z

Comment: If the url is ```/fr/equiper?editeur=editeur1``` this checkbox ```<input id="edit" name="editeur" type="checkbox" value="edit">"``` will be checked. And I want ```#domaine``` that includes checkboxes with ```data-editeur="edit"``` to have the ```class="open"```.